# asp.net mvc2 validation acting different on two servers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, viewmodel

I am having a issue, and I don’t know which result is correct.

I am obtaining two different scenarios depending on where I run the application from - local (debug mode) / development  (on a separate server).

I have one view model ConsultationViewModel over two .aspx pages (I want to remember the data between the two forms).

Form 1
Two objects (strings) – One [Required]

Form 2 
Two objects (strings) – Two [Required]

Here is where I obtain different scenarios:

•   Local Host: Form 1 – Form 2 = NO validation errors
•   Development: Form 1– Form 2 = Validation error

Form 1

```
public string Rate { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter your comments")]
public string Comments { get; set; }
```

Form 2

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a option")]
public string WhatAreYou { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a option")]
public string EthnicOrigin { get; set; }
```

Why on the development server does it need to validate WhatAreYou/EthinicOrigin is these are actually never used on Form 2?

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ConsultationHolderViewModel consultationViewModel = new ConsultationViewModel();
        return View(consultationViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ConsultationViewModel consultationViewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(consultationViewModel);
        }

        return View("Equalities", consultationViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Equalities(ConsultationViewModel consultationViewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(consultationViewModel);
        }

        switch (consultationViewModel.Button)
        {
            case "Back":
                return View("Index", consultationViewModel);
            case "Continue":
                return View("Receipt", consultationViewModel);
        }

        return View("Equalities", consultationViewModel);
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help,

Clare

Answer (score 0):

my bet is it has something to do with default mvc2 model binding. It validates all model properties.

So if your model has them, even if you don't post them or even don't need  them - you will still get validation errors.

Comment: I manually populate the required fields before the ModelState.IsValid it still displays the error messages: consultationViewModel.WhatAreYou = "A"; /             consultationViewModel.EthnicOrigin = "A"; Why would it do this? As both strings do contain data

Comment: Well, I guess it is already not valid by the time Your action method gets called. You might want to add those missing fields asd HiddenFor() in your view.. and be done with it